# How to randomize Motion/animation without create a state for each animation?

Tags: unity, animation

I'm using Animator and state for animating my charachter.

So, i've (example) an Idle state, associated to an Idle motion animation , and a Death State, associated to a Death animation.

But I've 5 possible animation for death so i would like to randomize death animation without create a state for each animation.

My State "Death" has a "Motion" variable. I would like to change at runtime this  "motion" variable. Is it possible ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/animator-random-animation-parameter.263464/#post-1742985):

> In 5.0 we introduced StateMachine Transition which can be used to
>   generate random animation from a list see this blog for an example
>   http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/26/shiny-new-animation-features-in-unity-5-0/
>
> in 4.x you can emulate this by creating a sub statemachine, with a
>   first state that act like a selector; put a small clip(a few frame
>   only) in this state that blend corrrectly to all your other random
>   state, for each transition make sure that you don't have an exit time,
>   you want to change as fast as possible from this selector state to
>   your random state.
>
> [image]

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a quick summary of how to do this in the more modern versions (5 or later) rather than relying on an external link.

Comment: @DMGregory You are right.